# TCL script: variable as argument of a function

Tags: tcl

I am trying some simple scripting with Amira, which uses TCL but I cannot assure that it's the standard version.
I want to read a property from an object and assign it to another object.

In the command window the procedure would be the following:

> Image1 getTransform

0.1 0.2 0.3 0 0 0 0 0 0 1

> Image2 setTransform 0.1 0.2 0.3 0 0 0 0 0 0 1

I want to do the same without manually copy pasting the result of getTransform

The following do not work (taht is to say setTransform is executed without arguments)

```
Image2 setTransform [Image1 getTransform]
```

or

```
set myT=Image1 getTransform
Image2 setTransform $myT
```

I am sure I just need to appropriately use $ [ { , but what I've tried so far has not given any result

Comment: The command to determine the Tcl version is `info patchlevel`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Tcl 8.5 or newer, then use the `{*}` argument expansion:

```
Image2 setTransform {*}[Image1 getTransform]
```

which is exactly what you want.

If you are using an older version of Tcl, then you have to use `eval`, a very useful command, where many things can go wrong if not used correctly:

```
eval [linsert [Image1 getTransform] 0 Image2 setTransform]
```

The `linsert` is used here to build up a propper list to avoid double substitution (which is almost always bad).

Comment: Thank you, both instructions work! - but I prefer the first one :)

Comment: Right, the first one is the better one. But it only works with Tcl 8.5 or newer.